# IntelliJ IDEA always shows MockitoAopProxyTargetInterceptor as autowired

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Every `@Bean` has the autowired icon in the gutter in IntelliJ IDEA and when I click on it to see what is autowired it always shows Mockito as autowired.

[image]

I'm not sure why it's happening, did I misconfigure something? How can I tell IntelliJ IDEA not to show `MockitoAopProxyTargetInterceptor` as autowired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the method in `MockitoAopProxyTargetInterceptor` is:

```
@Autowired public static void applyTo(Object source) {}
```

We have beans (annotated with `@Bean`) and places where they are used. This icon is the navigation to such places.

As the type of the `source` parameter is `Object`, every `@Bean` will be associated with this place and will have navigation usage to this `applyTo()` method.

What can we do:

1. Don't show navigation to autowired injection points of `Object` type
2. Reduce search scope (don't search in `test-library` scope where Mockito is placed)

I've created the request for this: [IDEA-172429](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172429). Please follow for updates.